# Simple XML Parsing in Android

Tags: android, xml

My xml is shown below:

```
<.sUID>yPkmfG3caT6cxexj5oWy34WiUUjj8WliWit45IzFVSOt6gymAOUA==<./sUID>
<.Shipping>0.00<./Shipping>
<.DocType>SO<./DocType>
```

How do I parse this simple xml in Android?

Comment: Please read this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) for simple XML Parsing.

Comment: Have you done google? becoz as of now, There are many Examples available for parsing XML using DOM Parser, SAX Parser, Pull Parser and other parsing techniques.

Comment: XML must have a parent wrapping the content. Like: <XML>your xml here</XML>

Answer (score 5):

Make a document:

```
public Document XMLfromString(String v){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(v));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;

    }
```

Then read it like so:

```
Document doc = x.XMLfromString("<XML><sUID>yPkmfG3caT6cxexj5oWy34WiUUjj8WliWit45IzFVSOt6gymAOUA==</sUID> <Shipping>0.00</Shipping> <DocType>SO</DocType></XML>");

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("XML");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the default pull XML parser is tedious and error-prone since the API is too low level. Use [Konsume-XML](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml):

```
data class Shipment(val uid: String, val shipping: BigDecimal, val docType: String) {
    companion object {
        fun xml(k: Konsumer): Shipment {
            k.checkCurrent("Shipment")
            return Shipment(k.childText("sUID"),
                    k.childText("Shipping") { it.toBigDecimal() },
                    k.childText("DocType"))
        }
    }
}

val shipment = """
<Shipment>
    <sUID>yPkmfG3caT6cxexj5oWy34WiUUjj8WliWit45IzFVSOt6gymAOUA==</sUID>
    <Shipping>0.00</Shipping>
    <DocType>SO</DocType>
</Shipment>
""".trimIndent().konsumeXml().child("Shipment") { Shipment.xml(this) }
println(shipment)
```

will print `Shipment(uid=yPkmfG3caT6cxexj5oWy34WiUUjj8WliWit45IzFVSOt6gymAOUA==, shipping=0.00, docType=SO)`