# Special parsing XML with Simple XML

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

How to parse the XML fragment with SimpleXML in Android?

```
<txtList>
    message <bold>message</bold> message
</txtList>
```

In fact, I do not know how to retrieve the value of an element that contains another element in this way?

Comment: found this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548807/simple-xml-parsing-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a class with proper fields. Or - and thats what i recommend - you write a class that contains the values and a [`Transformer`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transformer.html) which "parses" the XML.

However, Simple XML ist *not* a XML-Parser, it's a *Serializer*. So you may have a look at e.g. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), a very good HTML / XML Parser.